# How can I list the usernames in safe mode?

Tags: password, login

I originally set up my Raspberry Pi to start up without requiring a login username and password, but some friends (still friends in spite of it all) did something so that it now requires a login. Unfortunately I did not make a note of whatever the username and password were, and trying all the obvious ones doesn't work. I have read of safe mode, and now have a command line after shorting pins 5 and 6. What I need to know now is to find out what usernames are available, or stored, and then I can set a password. Please can someone tell me how?

Alternatively, is there a way, at this safe mode command line, to set it back to the state where no login is needed?

Comment: The superuser (root) can set the passwords for other users.  If you look at /home there will be a directory for each created user.  This is more of a general Unix/Linux question and is not specific to the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2):

`cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd` will list all users.

---

**To Change Password**

`sudo su [USER]` and then you could use `raspi-config` to change the password, as it does not require the current password to be entered.

Comment: Another possibility to do this en masse for a number of users, if you have root access or can edit `/etc/passwd` with `sudo`, is to just remove the `x` in the second field so you are left with, e.g., `pi::1001` instead of `pi:x:1001`.  This leaves that user with no password; when asked, just hit enter.  You can then set a password with `passwd`.  The autologin stuff can be configured via `raspi-config` (see the choices under "Boot Options").